# Parsing a String Java

Tags: java, xml

I have the following fields in my XML

```
<NOPC_NOTE_LINE1></NOPC_NOTE_LINE1>
<NOPC_NOTE_LINE2><NOPC_NOTE_LINE2>
<NOPC_NOTE_LINE3><NOPC_NOTE_LINE3>
```

In my JAVA code I have

```
service028.setNote1();
service028.setNote2();
service028.setNote3();
```

setnote2 can only take a max of 60 characters. The user should be able to enter 110 characters. If the user enters more than 60 characters I want to take the remaining characters and put them into setNote3 which should allow 50 characters

Any good way to do this?

Comment: Use an XML parser, add the lines to one string and then split as needed.

Comment: where are you stuck? you don't know how to measure the length of a String? how to cut it? show what you've done so far

Comment: whats with setnote1? how many characters there?

Comment: @kaya 60 characters allowed in each. setNote1 is taken up with prefilled text

Comment: @sharonbn yes I can String length() and then I have tried if(str.length() > 50)
    strOut = str.substring(0,49) + "...";

Comment: so where is the problem ???

Comment: why not if(str.length() > 60)? note: str.substring(0,49) gives you a string with length 49, not 50

Comment: What's your question? What's the relationship between the XML and the Java Code? Which string do you want to parse?

Comment: And [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Have a single setNote method that handles it and calls the others, based on string length.. 110 chars means that setNote3 will never be called, if you're allowing 60 chars for note1 and note2 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
        if (stringValue.length() > 60) {
            service028.setNote2(stringValue.substring(0, 60));
            service028.setNote3(stringValue.substring(60));
        } else {
            service028.setNote2(stringValue);
        }
```

Comment: did you mean "divide by 60"? also, no reason to only put 58 characters since OP allowed 60

Comment: ohh, long time since i used modulo, my bad im fixing this and trying right in IDE

Comment: You don't need those stringValue.length() bits. substring(n) goes from n to the end of the string anyway.

Comment: @kaya going to try now and let you know